# What can I do to show my app on google results?

Tags: google, google-search, search-engines

I uploaded my website to the server 2 days ago. I'm already being indexed by google and bing. I have a sitemap that they can read as it's confirmed in my g-analytic report and webmaster tools. Robots are find. I set the title, description, keywords. However, the website is not showing up on google results with keywords contained in my website title, description and so on. Is that the normal behavior considering that my web has been published just for 48 hours or less?

I must say I have strong competitors because is a website about puzzles and crosswords. Yet I feel I'm not doing things well. I'm open to any suggestion. I know it's too sun to get frustrated but still...

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you don't rank high enough to be on a first or even second page listing. If you're using generic terms in your tile and there is high competition on those keywords, you might not show up unless you are able to drive consistent traffic to your site somehow.

For example, if your website is called "Puzzle Games," even though the keyword `puzzle games` is the title of your website, your website might not show. There may already be enough established sites with that are relevant to that keyword that your site won't show.

Comment: That's part of what is happening. I can't call my website differently. It's a website to create and solve crosswords opened to all public. How can I call it? I'm hoping that is just because has been online just for 3 days counting today. It's so frustatring. If I don't promote myself the page, not a single visitor shows up, because of course, the website doesn't show up on search results. :(

Comment: You can promote yourself through other means to gain popularity. Post links on Facebook or Twitter until your website gains enough visitors to rank higher in the search results. Or change your name to something more unique. Even something like "Dan's Puzzles" will help you.

Comment: That's what I do, but I can't do that everyday. And by doing it I just make 2 or 3 people visit the page and leave after a while without creating any crossword. The only way I can make people participate is if my visitors are 200 or 300 not 2 or 3, because there are more chances that the right people are in 300 than in 3. I'm going to follow some advices in the duplicated question that someone pointed out to see what happens.